# clojurescript iterate over the keys of an object

Tags: clojurescript

I am using clojurescript 0.0-2371 and I am trying to write some code that will clone an object.  I have this code where I want to clone a node and calls a `clone-object` function:

```
(def animate
  (js/React.createClass
   #js
   {:getInitialState
    (fn []
      (this-as this
               {:children
                (->
                 (.. this -props -children)
                 (js/React.Children.map (fn [child] child))
                 (js->clj :keywordize-keys false))}))
    :render
    (fn []
      (this-as this
               (let [children (:children (.. this -state))]
                 (doseq [[k v] children]
                   (clone-object (aget children k))))))}))
```

`clone-object` looks like this:

```
(defn clone-object [obj]
  (log/debug obj)
  (doseq [[k v] obj]
    (log/debug k)))
```

And if I call `clone-object` like this:

```
(doseq [[k v] children]
  (clone-object v))
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: [object Object] is not ISeqable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer was to use `goog.object.forEach`:

```
(defn clone-object [key obj]
  (goog.object/forEach obj
     (fn [val key obj]
        (log/debug key))))
```

Comment: Why the `key` argument ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't strictly need Google Closure for looping through keys:

```
(defn obj->vec [obj]
  "Put object properties into a vector"
  (vec (map (fn [k] {:key k :val (aget obj k)}) (.keys js/Object obj)))
  )

; a random object
(def test-obj (js-obj "foo" 1 "bar" 2))

; let's make a vector out of it
(def vec-obj (obj->vec test-obj))

; get the first element of the vector and make a key value string
(str (:key (first vec-obj)) ":" (:val (first vec-obj)))
```

About `obj->vec`:

- `vec` convert a sequence to a vector (optional in case you are ok with a sequence)
- `map` execute `(fn [k] ...)` for each element of the list.
- `(fn [k] ...)` Take the `k` element of the list and put it in a key/value map data structure, `aget` takes the `obj` property referred by the key `k`.
- `(.keys js/Object obj)` Get all the keys from a js object.